# Can I extract properties to array or object from Measure-PnpWeb?

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell

I am fairly new to PnP PowerShell. I am trying to extract the `TotalFileSize` property from what the `Measure-PnPWeb` returns so I can see the total file size from my site.

I've tried extracting to client-side object and just an error that the WebStatistics cannot be converted to a client-side object.

Any idea how to get the values of the properties after running `Measure-PnPWeb`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it into a variable.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com" -DeviceLogin
$measurement = Measure-PnPWeb # at this point, you're assigning returned object of Measure-PnPWeb into $measurement
$measurement.TotalFileSize #from which you can use it in any of your expression
if ($measurement.TotalFileSize -gt 1000) {
    #if size > 1000, then do something here...
}
```

Hope this helps.